# Unintentional Form Submit After a Successful Submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

Our site has a form that is injected into a jQuery dialog.  Upon entering form data and clicking the submit button (a jQueryUI dialog button), the form is first validated by javascript then submitted to the server.  I have found that after pasting in a value to the one textbox that is mandatory and submitting, occasionally when I open the form the next time, it attempts to submit immediately without the user clicking the button (I verified this with debugger statements just before every instance of `.submit()` which were hit only when form submission happened with a button click).

Has anyone else encountered an instance of unintended form submission, and other than server side validation was there any way you could combat it?

Just to be clear, the order of events are as follows:

1. User clicks the Add button which gets the form (partial view) and injects it into the dialog, then opens the dialog.
2. User pastes a value into the mandatory textbox (there are several other controls).
3. User clicks the Submit button which performs low level validation and submits the form via ajax, closing the dialog after success.
4. Rinse and repeat until:
5. User clicks the Add button which gets the form and injects it into the dialog, which opens and them immediately submits, failing validation on the server.

## Form.submit callback

```
    $("#SearchEdit>form").submit(function (e) {
        if (TermPresent()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    });

function TermPresent() {
    return ($("textarea#MySearch_SearchTerms").val() != "" ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, then summit from the bottom of your validation code instead of allowing the form to submit itself.

Comment: The button in question is one of the Dialogs buttons, created via jSon property, so it is not type=submit.  The click callback on it runs the validation then calls `$("form#NewSearchTerm").submit();` and in fact, the form submit call comes on the success callback of an ajax call to do server-side validation.  When the form is erroneously submitted, it is not validating on the client, it is not validating on the server, it is bypassing all code.

Comment: You need to intercept the submit event on your form and use preventDefault to stop it from submitting. Need to see your JS to help.

Comment: While it is not a big problem (in fact it hardly impacts things at all since there is validation in place on the server to handle it, with the form submit handling in place, it appears to try and submit the form multiple times.  I will post the handler code I am implementing above.  That is the only change I have made, so I can't figure out why it is trying it repeatedly.  I will go ahead and mark as the answer, though.

Comment: You can always disable the submit button until you get your AJAX response.

Comment: I don't think it is executing the submit button code multiple times.  I am not really sure exactly what is going on.  Regardless, at this time it is not a concern as the multiple submissions are handled.  I will devote some more time to it in a later sprint.